# Initial Connection for network setup from Smartphone to raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have Raspberry Pi 3 model B
OS: Raspbian(jessie)

I want to create a connection from my smartphone to a headless raspberry, and connect the headless raspberry to a network(which the smartphone is conencted).
like the vacum cleaner robot (IRobot) or Web camera which has an app, or any device that needs an initial connection to setup it's network.

the initial connection needs to be from a remote device, mainly a smartphone app.

What  did i try:
1. bluetooth - i've managed to setup the bluetooth in the raspberry. when i try to connect, a popup appears on the raspberry which ask to confirm connection, because the raspberrry needs to be headless, this option is not good for us.
if i set the bluetooth as follow: sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0
when i try to connect to the raspberry, a popup appears in the smartphone required a PIN code, this option may be good, if i new the PIN code.
2. P2P - i try use wifi direct from my smartphone 
i've create file called p2p.conf inside /etc/wap_supplicant
inside this file i wrote the following:

```
ctrl_interface/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
device_name=raspberry
device_type=1-0050F204-1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
p2p_go_intent=1
p2p_go_ht40=1
```

then stop the wpa_supplicant  and change
sudo wpa_supplicant  -B -iwlan0 -Dnl80211 -c/etc/p2p.conf

i've started wpa_cli
and then p2p_find
it's started scanning
when i search from the smartphone for the raspberry, i found the raspberry, when i try to conenct it asks me for PIN code, the PIN code is showen in the raspberry wpa_cli.
two problem i have from this option:
1. the network needs to be connected.
2. the PIN code changes, and i can't make it fixed.

Is there a way to make an initial connection to setup a network from the smartphone to a headless raspberry?